# Remove fixed masthead and footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, cover

Is there a way to remove the fixed masthead and footer from the Cover bootstrap template? I've been searching through the files and made some edits but can't see any real changes.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

Comment: Lol. Getting downvotes after I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change position fixed masthead and footer from the Cover bootstrap template, for that you will need to overwrite few bootstrap classes

**Overwrite**

```
.site-wrapper-inner {
 /*  vertical-align:middle;  REMOVED */
  vertical-align:top; /* ADDED */
}
.masthead {
  /*  position: fixed;  REMOVED */
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}
.mastfoot {
 /*  position: fixed;  REMOVED */
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}
```

If you want to remove those elements completely then either you can add "hidden" class to the mastheadand mastfoot as follows

```
<div class"masthead hidden"></div>
<div class"mastfoot hidden"></div>
```

**0R**

```
.masthead {
  display:none
}
.mastfoot {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.masthead` and `.mastfoot` elements... or set them to `display:none`, like:

```
.masthead, .mastfoot{
    display:none;
}
```